# Insert dynamically in database using ajax

Tags: java, javascript, ajax, jsp

I have a jsp which shows some records and now I want to add a link/button in jsp for insert in the database dynamically without refreshing the page.

that link opens a pop-up with some input field and submit button where I can insert in Db and that redirect me to same jsp without refreshing.

Guys help me or provide me some link ... this is completely  new to me..

thanks

Comment: Post the html form you are using for inputs.

Comment: use jquery.ajax to post the data to a servlet, which will insert the data

Comment: @aashish_soni check my answer n plz reply back..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here the code to submit a form from the client to your controller.

```
$.ajax({
    dataType: "json",
    method: "POST",
    url: 'publicProcurements/' + publicProcurementId + '/selectCandidates/informCandidacies/saveInformCandidacies.do',
    data: $('#informCandidaciesForm').serialize(),
    success: function (data) {
        //Whatever you want, like close the dialog
    }
});
```

About the logic of how to save this form on database on the controller is too much code to provided. Here we response questions, don't make code for you my friend.

Comment: @ScaryWombat what do you mean?

Comment: a minute ago, someone had down-voted you.  I was wondering why

Comment: @ScaryWombat I dont know, maybe because part of the question was resolved?. I asume you was the one that remove that vote. Thanks buddy

Comment: Sorry, I can not remove some-one elses DV - I wish

Answer (score 0):

First of all write an click function for that

```
$('#id_button').click(function(){
        //get all the required parameters using jquery here using .val
          var param1 = $('#param1').val();
        //alert(s_id);
        $.post('../servlet_name',{param1:param1},function(msg) {

 });
```

Next in your servlet `request.getParameter("param1")` and do the insertion part here.

Next pass a response back to the ajax saying its done,for example a flag

```
PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();
writer.println("1");
```

Back to the ajax function now
This value will be retrieved as msg in the ajax function
here msg will be equal to 1 as you had sent it from the servlet

Next you can alert your user that data is inserted

```
$.post('../servlet_name',{param1:param1},function(msg) {
        if(msg=="1"){
          alert("data added");
        }
     });
```

Hope this helps

Comment: have a look at @paul 's answer for a cleaner and safer way

Comment: @ScaryWombat $post isnt safe?

Comment: post is safe, I would rather serialize the form though

Comment: @ScaryWombat oh lyk dat..But i just gave an example of a single parameter not a form..even for a single paramter i need to serialize?

Comment: also I would go for a success block.  I am not saying your way is not valid though

Answer (score 0):

The answer depends on what you want.

The link/button in your HTML file:

```
<a href='' id='insertButton'>Insert</a>
```

Script for ajax (be sure to place this after including jQuery plugin):

```
$("#insertButton").click(function(event){

    var request = $.ajax({

        type: "POST", //default is GET
        url: "controller/action", //replace with your method URL
        data: {} //here you pass the parameters (ex. data:{name: 'John', age: 45}) 

    });
    request.done(response){
        console.log("Response:");
        console.log(response);
        yourCallbackFunction(response); //Update view with the response
    }
    request.fail(error){
        console.log("Error:");
        console.log(error);
    }

    return false; //so the user won't be redirected by input's submit behavior.

});
```

If you need to sync your View (html) with your DB dynamically, you should take a look at [Angular JS](https://angularjs.org/) and [Firebase](https://www.firebase.com/).